# Web2py, multiple Ajax calls and session variables stored in MySQL

Tags: mysql, session, web2py, pickle

In order for a progress bar using cache.ram, and an ajax call to work properly, there is a need to clean (or just unlock?) sessions.
If the app doesn't use session variables to pass to other controllers then session.forget(response) is sufficient.

If on the other hand, the app needs session variables (as my app does indeed) - then session.forget doesn't do much good since it brakes the session variables chain of transmission to other controllers.

As per Anthony suggestion in another post (Progress bar and sessions) on Web2Py google group:

I tried first using the cookies (with maximum zlib compression - level 9) . 
Still it's not enough for my needs ... I need more than 10k per session to be passed to other controllers, and as mentioned in the book - keeping sessions in cookies is not a good solution if the session are expected to be large (more than 4k/cookie I assume).

So I am trying session.connect with a MySQL db.
I can see the table web2py_session_AppName being populated and I understand the session_data column is pickled with cPickle.
However...It looks the data in this column, session_data is encrypted, not just pickled.

How do I unpickle the information in session_data column from a MySQL table ? 
I tried using cPickle.loads...with the data as is, with the data as a string...but it still throws a "bad pickle error"

Here is the controller:

```
def index():
    session.Yawza = 'Yawza from index'
    cache.ram(CacheKeyUID, lambda: 0, 0)
    return dict()

def cache_in_ram():
    for i in range(int(1e5)):
        avoda = int((i/(1e5))*100)
        cache.ram(CacheKeyUID, lambda:avoda, 0)
    session.Yawza = "Yawza from the cache_in_ram"
    redirect(URL('Test'))

def cache_reader():
    return cache.ram(CacheKeyUID, lambda: None, None)

def test():
    return dict(message = 'Long process ended')
```

The above will have the progress bar work ONLY the first time. After that progress bar will not work (due to locking by the multiple ajax calls) - unless I manually clear sessions or programmatically do a *session.forget(response)* which will unfortunately eliminate the session.Yawza. I need this session.Yawza for OTHER purposes than the progress bar, in other controllers down stream.

Adding *session.connect(request,response,cookie_key='yoursecret',compression_level=9)* to my db.py helps, but is limited to 4k size cookies. I need bigger cookies than that. Thus, I moved towards storing sessions in the db, which in my case is a MySQL db.

Defined *session.connect(request, response, db)* in db.py. I can see in MySQL the table *web2py_session_AppName* being populated, but I do NOT have access to session.Yawza at all. 
Not from the index function and not from the cache_in_ram function.

That's the reason I thought I should MANUALLY unpickle the session_data column...to get access to session.Yawza which must be hiding there.

Here is a small sample of what can be found in the session_data column in the MySQL table for web2py_sessions_MyAppName :
gAJjZ2x1b24uZ2xvYmFscwpTZXNzaW9uCnEBfXECVQVZYXd6YXEDVQ1mcm9tIHRleHQgYm9...

It doesn't look like a kosher pickle to me ...
;-))

What am I doing or not doing correctly in order to benefit from the multiple ajax calls, no sessions locking and still use session variables to transfer info to other controllers ?

Comment: The session data are not encrypted -- [here](https://github.com/web2py/web2py/blob/master/gluon/globals.py#L1177) is where it is saved to the db, and [here](https://github.com/web2py/web2py/blob/master/gluon/globals.py#L940) is where it is retrieved (note, just a standard `pickle.loads`). Anyway, why do you need to retrieve and unpickle the data manually -- why not just connect and get the data from the `session` object?

Comment: Also, if you are using `cache.ram` to store the progress information, why do you need the session? Using `session.forget(response)` during the Ajax calls used to check `cache.ram` will have no effect on using the session in other requests. You shouldn't need the session during those Ajax calls. It might help if you show your code so a proper solution can be suggested.

Comment: Anthony, If I use MySQL for session storage - I cannot access them. Thus, I thought I need unpickle them manually...

Comment: I need the session variable for OTHER purposes than the Ajax - for other controllers.

Comment: Note, if you are storing sessions in the database but having trouble, you have done something wrong; though it is hard to say what without seeing the code. Anyway, you shouldn't need to move sessions to the database.

Comment: Also, you can "forget" sessions for a single request without affecting usage of the session in any other requests. Just be sure to call `session.forget(response)` *inside* the controller function where you want to forget/unlock the session (i.e., don't execute that code in a model or at the top level of the controller, as it will then affect other controller actions as well).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might consider whether you can alter the long running `cache_in_ram` function without having to write to the session. In that case, you can call `session.forget(response)` at the beginning of that function, and everything will work fine, even with the default file-based sessions (i.e., no need to move sessions to cookies or the database).

If you must write to the session from within the `cache_in_ram` request, you can first unlock the session, then run the long loop, and then re-open the session and update it as needed:

```
def cache_in_ram():
    session.forget(response) # Unlock the session file.
    for i in range(int(1e5)):
        avoda = int((i/(1e5))*100)
        cache.ram(CacheKeyUID, lambda:avoda, 0)
    session.connect() # Re-open/lock the session file.
    session._forget = False # Reverse the "forget" so we can write to the session.
    session.Yawza = "Yawza from the cache_in_ram"
    redirect(URL('Test'))
```

Alternatively, you can switch to storing sessions in the database, which does not do any locking and therefore will not cause the Ajax progress checks to be blocked by the long-running `cache_in_ram` request. In that case, there is no need to manually read and unpickle the session data from the database -- just use the `session` object as usual. If you find you cannot access the session data as expected in this case, then you have done something wrong either in setting up the connection or in how you are writing to/reading from the session. You should post a separate question about that, showing all of your code.

Comment: Many thanks Anthony ! It is now finally working: both the progress bar AND the session variables. And I do not need to debug what exactly I did wrong with storing the sessions in the db...which from the beginning did not seem as not the most pythonic way to solve the issue at hand. Thanks !